# replacing a specific column with a declared variable using awk

Tags: awk

Let's consider the following example

I have a file say, "filename" which contains the following data

```
141     VALE141P        -2.36741
142     ILEE142M        -0.978118
143     ASNE143L        -0.65645
144     HISE144R        137.373
145     THRE145T        -3.11502e-11
146     SERE146G        -0.305383
147     ASPE147L        -1.36308
148     ARGE148R        -6.82121e-13
149     HISE149E        166.234
150     ARGE150P        -1.81996
```

I want to replace the 3rd column if it the value is greater than 0 with declared variable (which will be taken from other file).

I tried with the following code

```bash
var=0
line=($(awk '{if ($3>0) {line=NR; print line}}' filename))
for N in ${line[@]}
 do
  awk '{if (NR=='$N') {$3='$var'}; {print}}' filename > temporaryfile
 done
```

The output is coming as following

```
141     VALE141P        -2.36741
142     ILEE142M        -0.978118
143     ASNE143L        -0.65645
144     HISE144R        137.373
145     THRE145T        -3.11502e-11
146     SERE146G        -0.305383
147     ASPE147L        -1.36308
148     ARGE148R        -6.82121e-13
149     HISE149E        0
150     ARGE150P        -1.81996
```

Ideally both 4th and 9th line 3rd column value should be replaced by 0. However, I am not getting it. Can you please let me know what's wrong with this code?

Note that for simplicity here, I set the variable as 0.

Comment: You say the replacement value 'taken from other file' but you don't us any other vile just a variable. You don't need this silly and horribly inefficient shell looping to do what awk is designed to do better; to change all column 3 (numerically) greater than 0 to a variable in the same shell, run _one_ command: `awk -v v="$var" '$3>0{$3=v} {print}' infile >outfile`. It's unclear if this qualifies as programming.

Comment: This loop is constructed as the variable will be taken, along with some other calculations from another file which will also run inside the loop. It's just simplified version only. @dave_thompson_085

Comment: @AkashMondal the problem you are using the filename in your loop instead of using the  temporaryfile..  Try first to copy the filename to temporaryfile and use ` -i inplace ` in the second awk with the temporaryfile

Comment: If you copy/paste your shell script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about then you will learn how to use quotes in shell programming. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a single call to awk:

```bash
awk '
    $3 > 0 {$3 = 0}
    {print}
' filename   > tmpfile && mv tmpfile filename
```

Or as a "one-liner"

```bash
awk '$3 > 0 {$3 = 0} 1' filename > t && mv t filename
```

---

Note that will alter the spacing of the file. If the file is tab-separated, do this:

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
    $3 > 0 {$3 = 0}
    {print}
' filename   > tmpfile && mv tmpfile filename
```

Or as a one-liner

```bash
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '$3 > 0 {$3 = 0} 1' filename > t && mv t filename
```

---

Putting awk or sed in a shell loop to update the same file is a bit of an antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

var=0
read -r -d"\n" -a lines < <(awk '$3>0{print NR}' filename)
cp filename temporaryfile

for N in "${lines[@]}"
 do
  # some other calculations
  ...
  ...
  # using only temporaryfile with '-i inplace' to save the changes
  awk -v nr="$N" -v var="$var" -v OFS="\t" -i inplace 'NR==nr{$3=var}1' temporaryfile
done

$ cat temporaryfile
141     VALE141P        -2.36741
142     ILEE142M        -0.978118
143     ASNE143L        -0.65645
144     HISE144R        0
145     THRE145T        -3.11502e-11
146     SERE146G        -0.305383
147     ASPE147L        -1.36308
148     ARGE148R        -6.82121e-13
149     HISE149E        0
150     ARGE150P        -1.81996
```